# Relocate bladder and transducer?

Tags: well

I keep having surging problems on my well. It has the variable speed pump (2 hp ) with Aquavar Solo pump controller and inline bladder about 60' down.
Can I install a pressure tank and transducer in the pumphouse, leaving bladder and original transducer down in the well?
From the well is a tee for irrigation, and then to pump house where water softener is located, and finally to house.

Comment: Probably, but there isn't much detail to work with here. Consider an [edit] to add some: make and model of pump, controller, etc...

Comment: I thought all well pumps used a pressure tank to prevent surging/on and off operation.

Comment: They do, but variable speed pumps can use a smaller one, and approximate constant pressure by varying pump speed to meet demand. Of course, locating that 50 feet down a hole does not exactly make it easy to check when/if it fails, so the genius that came up with that location was probably angling for big money on future service calls.